# In VB, how do I use IndexOf function to find the second time something appears

Tags: vb.net, web-scraping, console-application, webclient, indexof

I am writing a function that takes the HTML code from a website, looks at the name of which `span class` I want to extract some information from and then extract it. One of the other parameters I am trying to add to my function is a number which specifies which `span class` you want to search for (whether it is the first, second or third etc. occurrence)

I have gotten the main part of the function working (finding the `span class` an extracting it's information), but I want to get the "occurrence" part working too.

Here is my code:

```
Function RetrieveClass(ByRef URL, ByRef ClassToRetrieve, ByRef ClassIndex)
        Const QUOTE = """"

        'Loading the website's HTML code and storing it in a HTML as a string:
        Dim Client As New WebClient
        'URL = "https://jisho.org/search/%E5%8F%AF%E6%84%9B%E3%81%84" 'used to test on the 可愛い page

        Dim HTML As String = Client.DownloadString(New Uri(URL))

        'Used to debug:
        Console.WriteLine(HTML)
        Console.WriteLine("URL: " & URL)

        Dim SnipIndex As Integer = HTML.IndexOf("class=" & QUOTE & ClassToRetrieve) 'Start of the snip, this will look for the class name, example: <span class="meaning-meaning">cute; adorable; charming; lovely; pretty</span>

        If SnipIndex = -1 Then
            Return ("Error: |" & "span class=" & QUOTE & ClassToRetrieve & "| Not Found")
        End If
        Dim Snip As String = Mid(HTML, SnipIndex + 10 + ClassToRetrieve.length, 50)
        SnipIndex = Snip.IndexOf("<")
        Snip = Left(Snip, SnipIndex)

        Console.WriteLine("SnipEnd: " & SnipIndex)
        Console.WriteLine("Snip: " & Snip)




        Console.ReadLine()
        Return (Snip)
    End Function
```

Some context: I am trying create a web scraper that takes definitions and more from a Japanese dictionary, this will be helpful for my language learning.

If you look,
`Dim SnipIndex As Integer = HTML.IndexOf("class=" & QUOTE & ClassToRetrieve)` is the line that finds the class that you are searching for. What I want is the [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b2fz03t(v=vs.110).aspx) function to search for the second occurrence of the `span class`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a simple for loop and run it n times. (searching the n'th appearance) Inside the loop you call indexOf(string, number), the number you can take from the previous runs index + length of the string. That way the second time the loop runs, it starts searching after the first appearance. And so on. You can simply save the index in a variable and use that to calculate where to start the next search. Initialize the variable with 0 before the loop...

Edit to clarify: You would have something like index = indexOf(string, index + string.length)

There might be a better way to do this, but this would definitely work.

Comment: I tried something something like this, but my brain just couldn't do it. I could try having another go, but I'm not sure that I'll get anywhere.

Comment: Its really not complicated. You 'For i as Integer = 1 to n', In the next line you have indented the bit I have given you above. And below that you have 'Next', that is not indented.

Comment: When you want to know how something works in vb and other programming languages like c/c++, take a look at the language reference on microsoft docs. Here is a link to the vb reference: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/) There you can also find info about for loops and about the indexOf() function.